# Java and Gnome3 - Is it possible to create a system tray icon?

Tags: java, linux, gnome-3

The common way of loading into the system tray (as explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html)) doesn't seem to work for Gnome 3:

```
SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
...
TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Tray Demo", popup);
...
tray.add(trayIcon);
```

Instead, you get a window on the task bar called "JavaEmbeddedFrame", and nothing in the tray area:

[image]   [image]

I also tried the [System Tray github project,](https://github.com/dorkbox/SystemTray) but it crashes gnome on my computer.

Is there currently any way to do this in java? I'm open to any solution -- awt, swing, or javafx.

Comment: The Gnome 3 tray shows up in the bottom left by default but you seem to be using some custom extensions?

Comment: Yea, using Topicons plus. Disabling the extension doesn't resolve the problem. Same result.

Comment: Facing simliar issue however, my icon is a black square top right

Comment: I ended up solving this by writing directly in GTK with JNI: https://github.com/JoshuaD84/HypnosMusicPlayer/tree/master/src/linux-tray-icon-gtk